# Issues with using amazon ec2 cloud service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use some instances from amazon ec2 cloud service. I chose an instance and set the size of the root to be 1TB. However, when I launch the instance it shows to have just 8 GB. What could be the issue.

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward, really... You have an 8GB filesystem on a 1TB hard drive...  What AMI are you using to launch the instance?

Answer (score 0):

> set the size of the root to be 1TB

Makes me believe you are using `some` Linux AMI. Depending on which Linux AMI you are using, It seems like the AMI is not extending the File system.

You need to run `resize2fs` on the said device. Usually it is `/dev/xvda1`. If you are not sure what is the name of the device, then run `df -h | grep "/$" | awk '{print $1}'` to find it out.

Once you have the device name, run `resize2fs /dev/<the_device_name>`.

In my case it would be `resize2fs /dev/xvda1`